# After reloading the datatable unable to select the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have data table and by making an AJAX req am reloading the new contents of the table.On successful AJAX after the table gets reloaded am unable to select check-boxes in the data table.Since i have multiple check-boxes i use class selector to select the rows in the table. My select event is present inside document.ready. Where am missing??

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: `$('.cmpny_id').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    var isChecked = $('.cmpny_id').is(':checked');
  });`
<input type="checkbox" name="company_ids[]" id="company_ids_" value="1" class="cmpny_id">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.cmpny_id', function(event) {
```

var isChecked = $('.cmpny_id').is(':checked'); 
});

this worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
 $(function(){
    $('#dataTableId').on('click','.cmpny_id',function(){
         alert("hi"); var isChecked = $('.cmpny_id').is(':checked'); 
    });
 });
```

Change the `dataTableId` as per your table id.